# Replacing messed up formatted list on Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have such list that all chapters and sub chapters are in a format like the one below.

```
__1________________________
__1__1_____________________
__1__2_____________________
__1__2__1__________________
```

Is there such way to change this list into the one below?

```
1
1.1
1.2
1.2.1
```

I have tried replace, however it replaces all _ of them with dots or spaces thus ruining the list nature.

Is there a way to do this using VBA, it doesn't have to be VBA in your answer, because I can work on it to format it to fit VBA. I have many documents like this containing thousands of rows.

Comment: Copy everything to a text editor supporting regular expressions, do the replacement over there and copy back to Excel.

Comment: @Dominique can you please elaborate on that one. Text editor like Word? Because, I am trying to do the above change in VBA, since there are many documents in that format containing thousands of rows.

Comment: No, not Word. I mean text editors which support regular expressions, like Notepad++, Ultra Edit, ...

Comment: @Dominique below answer is perfect, thus no need to go through the hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to correct your sample data quickly.

```
Sub Replacing_messed_up_formatted_list()
    Dim rng As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        With .Columns(1)
            .Replace what:=Chr(95), replacement:=Chr(46), lookat:=xlPart
            Do While Not .Find(what:=Chr(46) & Chr(46), lookat:=xlPart) Is Nothing
                .Replace what:=Chr(46) & Chr(46), replacement:=Chr(46), lookat:=xlPart
            Loop
            .Replace what:=Chr(32), replacement:=vbNullString, lookat:=xlPart
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                           FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 9), Array(1, 2))
            For Each rng In Intersect(.Parent.UsedRange, .Cells)
                If Right(rng.Value2, 1) = Chr(46) Then rng = Left(rng.Value2, Len(rng.Value2) - 1)
            Next rng
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: a1_1_1_1]      [image: A1_1_1_1_1]